# Haskell: State Monad

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I'm trying to learn Haskell. I wrote a code that uses a global state and can change it using two functions (i.e. change1 and change 2). Also, I have included lens so I can learn it too.   The problem is very last line of the code. I don't understand why I cannot include the two last lines together in the main. It'd run if I remove either of them.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Dd (main, ma, change1,change2, Dp(Dp))  where
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

data Dp = Dp {_sr  :: Int , _fl :: Int} deriving (Show)
makeLenses ''Dp

plus ::  Dp  -> Dp
plus  = over (sr) (+90)

mult4 ::  Dp  -> Dp
mult4 = over (fl) (*100)

change1 :: State Dp ()
change1 = modify plus

change2 :: State Dp () 
change2  = modify  mult4 

ma :: State Dp ()
ma  = do 
      change1
      change2 

main = do 
     runState ma (Dp 2 3)
     evalState ma (Dp 2 3)-- here is the problem
```

Edit: I'm a bit confused: Why below code runs without an error?

```
data Dp = Dp {_sr  :: Int , _fl :: Int} deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Dp
gs :: StateT Dp IO Int
gs = do 
d <- gets _sr
liftIO $ print (d)
dd<- uses sr (10<=)
if (dd) then 
            return (10)
            else return (90)
 main  =  do 
        runStateT gs (Dp 3 6)
        evalStateT gs (Dp 3 6)
```

Comment: `runState` returns `(a, s)` which means your `main` is using the `(,) a` monad. `evalState` doesn't return a value in the same monad, so they can't be composed with `do` notation.

Comment: Adding a type annotation to main can produce better error messages. You probably want to `print` the results to make everything type check.

Comment: I challenge the assertion that "It'd run if I removed either of them.". Have you tested this? When I try it, I get a complaint that `main` does not have an `IO` type.

Comment: @DanielWagner It doesn't complain for me if loaded using GHCi

Comment: `runState` returns `(a, s)` and `runStateT` returns `m (a, s)` i.e. `IO (a, s)` here. Similarly `IO a` for the `evalSTateT`. Now both are `IO ...`, so it's OK. This still won't perform any I/O though, just "return" the last integer. You can see the types in GHCi with the `:t` command at its prompt (e.g., `:t runStateT`).

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for your comment. Yes, I tested, and that's why I said it runs if I removed one of them. I don't know why it compiled on m machine!

Answer (score 4):

In your case `do-notation` is a syntactic sugar for

```
(runState ma (Dp 2 3)) >> (evalState ma (Dp 2 3))
```

The type of `(>>)` is `Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b` which means that `runState ma (Dp 2 3)` and `evalState ma (Dp 2 3)` must be in the same monad, but they are not

But the code doesn't work mostly for another reason. The function `main` has the following type annotation: `main :: IO a` which means that `main` expects an action to be performed in it (for example printing the results)

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ runState ma (Dp 2 3)
  print $ evalState ma (Dp 2 3)
```

That works, because

- type of `print $ runState ma (Dp 2 3)` is `IO ((), Dp)`
- type of `print $ evalState ma (Dp 2 3)` is `IO ()`

Hence, inferred type for `>>` is `IO ((), Dp) -> IO () -> IO ()` which doesn't violate `Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b`. And the resulting type is `IO ()` which suits for `main :: IO a`